# Problems with Loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I am trying to solve an issue..

On a column, I have some stock numbers (activecell). And I have one Sales number.

I have to subtract this Sales Number for the stock numbers until it's a 0. As an example:

```
Sales Number = 500

Result = 500 - StockNumber1
Result2 = Result - StockNumber2
Result3 = Result - StockNumber3
```

I am trying to figure out a way to do it in a loop.

Maybe something like:

```
i = 0
Do While SalesNumber > Activecell.Offset(i,0)
SalesNumber - ActiveCell(i,0)

i = i + 1

Loop
```

However, I have not found a solution yet..  There are like 3 stock numbers, usually. 
How can I do to stop the loop when the stock numbers are over? Does anyone have an idea?

I dont know I am clear enough.. Any doubts, please ask!

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
Dim i, SalesNumber, nRowMax

nRowMax = Rows.Count
SalesNumber  = 500

' my stock number starts at the cell A1:

i = 1

Do While SalesNumber > 0
  ' use this to avoid infinite loop:
  If (i > nRowMax) Then
    Exit Do
  ElseIf (IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1))) Then
    Exit Do
  End If

  SalesNumber = SalesNumber - Cells(i, 1)
  i = i + 1
Loop
```